# Battle system in rock , paper, scissors game unable to effectively pull hp values

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error, global

When entering a battle in my game, I update both the enemy and players hp as the battle progresses. The game is a basic Rock, Paper, Scissors battle type. I've deleted a lot a lot of the other command you can use to make it shorter but the error still occurs

Here is the code:

```
import random
equippedweapon = ['Bare Fists', 'Attack: ', 5]
backpack = []
hp = 10

def battle(diff):
    battleactive = 0
    if diff == 0:
      #WOLF PUP
      enemyhp = 10
      enemydef = 4
      while battleactive == 0:
        enemyrockpaperscissors = random.randint(0,2)
        if enemyrockpaperscissors == 0:
          print("The wolf looks agitated!") #ROCK
        elif enemyrockpaperscissors == 1:
          print("The wolf pup is on their guard") #PAPER
        elif enemyrockpaperscissors == 2: #SCISSORS
          print("The wolf pup isn't paying attention to you")
        print("What would you like to do? Equipped Weapon = " + str(equippedweapon[0])) #Access weapon name
        print("Enemy HP: " + str(enemyhp) + ", Your HP: " + str(hp))
        print("Attack [0], Defend [1], Distract [2], Heal [3]") #Deleted Defend, Distract, and Heal
        control = input('')                    
        if control == "0": #ROCK
            if enemyrockpaperscissors == 0: #ENEMY USED ROCK
              print("You and the wolf charge at each other")
              if equippedweapon[0][2] > enemydef: 
                print("You came out on top")
                damage = equippedweapon[0][2] - enemydef
                print(str(damage) + " damage inflicted")
                enemyhp -= damage
              else:
                print("No one comes out on top")
                print("No Damage Inflicted")
            elif enemyrockpaperscissors == 1: #ENEMY USED PAPER
              print("The wolf parries your attack and scratches you with its claws.")
              print("2 damage taken")
              hp -= 2
            elif enemyrockpaperscissors == 2: #ENEMY USED SCISSORS
              print("The wolf was caught off guard by your attack")
              damage = equippedweapon[0][2]
              print(str(damage) + " damage inflicted")
              enemyhp -= damage
                      
        if enemyhp <= 0 or hp <= 0:
          print("The Battle has ended")
          if hp <= 0:
            print("You got no items")
          else:
            print("You got a Wolf Pup Tooth")
            backpack.append("Wolf Pup Tooth")
          battleactive += 1

battle(0)
```

The Enemy HP properly subtracts and the check at the end works
The Player HP does not work.

I've tried pulling the HP variable into the function with another parameter and it properly runs and displays, however the HP is not properly changed after the battle is over (If the player loses 5 hp, it only lasts for that battle. The players hp is not -5 after the battle is over)

I expect for the hp to be a global variable and properly or for the battle function to properly return the hp after the battle has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Numerous issues. I've stayed with your code structure below however as a next step you might look to creating a character/monster [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) where the name, hp, weapon are all properties. This will allow you to abstract your code.

Also, use 4 space indents. If your indent is too deep the message is that your code structure needs work. Another good thing to do is to use a code linter.

```
import random
equippedweapon = ['Bare Fists', 'Attack: ', 5]
backpack = []
hp = 10
# create constants, this makes it easier to do your tests
ROCK = 0
PAPER = 1
SCISSORS = 2


def battle(diff, hp):
    battleactive = 0
    if diff == 0:
        # WOLF PUP
        enemyhp = 10
        enemydef = 4
        while battleactive == 0:
            enemyrockpaperscissors = random.randint(0, 2)
            if enemyrockpaperscissors == ROCK:
                print("The wolf looks agitated!")
            elif enemyrockpaperscissors == PAPER:
                print("The wolf pup is on their guard")
            elif enemyrockpaperscissors == SCISSORS:
                print("The wolf pup isn't paying attention to you")
# Multi-line prints can be more readable, also have a look at f-strings
            print("What would you like to do? Equipped Weapon = "
                  f"{str(equippedweapon[0])}")
# f-strings cast your int to str without you having to do so
            print(f"Enemy HP: {enemyhp}, Your HP: {hp}")
            print("Attack [0], Defend [1], Distract [2], Heal [3]")
# convert the string to int immediately - personal preference
            control = int(input(''))
            if control == ROCK:
                if enemyrockpaperscissors == ROCK:
                    print("You and the wolf charge at each other")
# you were indexing as [0][2] when you just needed [2]
                    if equippedweapon[2] > enemydef: 
                        print("You came out on top")
                        damage = equippedweapon[2] - enemydef
                        print(str(damage) + " damage inflicted")
                        enemyhp -= damage
                    else:
                        print("No one comes out on top")
                        print("No Damage Inflicted")
                elif enemyrockpaperscissors == PAPER:
                    print("The wolf parries your attack and scratches you with"
                          " its claws. 2 damage taken")
                    hp -= 2
                elif enemyrockpaperscissors == SCISSORS:
                    print("The wolf was caught off guard by your attack")
                    damage = equippedweapon[2]
                    print(str(damage) + " damage inflicted")
                    enemyhp -= damage        
            if enemyhp <= 0 or hp <= 0:
                print("The Battle has ended")
                if hp <= 0:
                    print("You got no items")
                else:
                    print("You got a Wolf Pup Tooth")
                    backpack.append("Wolf Pup Tooth")
                battleactive += 1


# pass your global HP through
battle(0, hp)
```